# launching laser_scan_assembler with periodic snapshotter

Tags: ros, laser-assembler, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i need to make a composite point cloud. For that in tutorial and in help i have seen ,i need to create laser_assembler package . i need to launch laser_scan_assembler launch file along with periodic_snapshotter file. but im new to ros and i don know how to create  a laser_assembler package ,and to launch laser_scan_assembler file with periodic_snaphotter,

please help me in these two issues .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103431/launching-laser_scan_assembler-with-periodic-snapshotter/) by [sivan](https://answers.ros.org/users/5364/sivan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start `roscore` and `rosbag` (I'm assuming that you are playing a pre-recorded bagfile)

Then use the `laser_scan_assembler.launch` file below. Of course, you can change the time buffer and maximum number of scans. I use the `odom` frame, but you can use `map`, if you prefer that!

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="laser_assembler" type="laser_scan_assembler" output="screen"  name="laser_scan_assembler">
    <param name="tf_cache_time_secs" type="double" value="475.0" />
    <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="4000000" />
    <param name="ignore_laser_skew" type="bool" value="true" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="/odom" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Follow this with periodic snapshotter (`rosrun periodic_snapshotter periodic_snapshotter`) I use the `periodic_snapshotter.cpp` file below. You can change the time buffer for the snapshotter in the `timerCallback`

```
/*********************************************************************
* Software License Agreement (BSD License)
*
*  Copyright (c) 2008, Willow Garage, Inc.
*  All rights reserved.
*
*  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
*  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
*  are met:
*
*   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
*     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
*   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
*     copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following
*     disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided
*     with the distribution.
*   * Neither the name of the Willow Garage nor the names of its
*     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
*     from this software without specific prior written permission.
*
*  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
*  "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
*  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
*  FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
*  COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
*  INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
*  BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
*  LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
*  CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
*  LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
*  ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
*  POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
*********************************************************************/

#include <cstdio>
#include <ros/ros.h>

// Services
#include "laser_assembler/AssembleScans.h"

// Messages
#include "sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h"


/***
 * This a simple test app that requests a point cloud from the
 * point_cloud_assembler every 80 seconds, and then publishes the
 * resulting data
 */
namespace laser_assembler
{

class PeriodicSnapshotter
{

public:

  PeriodicSnapshotter()
  {
    // Create a publisher for the clouds that we assemble
    pub_ = n_.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud> ("assembled_cloud", 1);

    // Create the service client for calling the assembler
    client_ = n_.serviceClient<AssembleScans>("assemble_scans");

    // Start the timer that will trigger the processing loop (timerCallback)
    timer_ = n_.createTimer(ros::Duration(80,0), &PeriodicSnapshotter::timerCallback, this);

    // Need to track if we've called the timerCallback at least once
    first_time_ = true;
  }

  void timerCallback(const ros::TimerEvent& e)
  {

    // We don't want to build a cloud the first callback, since we we
    //   don't have a start and end time yet
    if (first_time_)
    {
      first_time_ = false;
      return;
    }

    // Populate our service request based on our timer callback times
    AssembleScans srv;
    srv.request.begin = e.last_real;
    srv.request.end   = e.current_real;

    // Make the service call
    if (client_.call(srv))
    {
      ROS_INFO("Published Cloud with %u points", (uint32_t)(srv.response.cloud.points.size())) ;
      pub_.publish(srv.response.cloud);
    }
    else
    {
      ROS_ERROR("Error making service call\n") ;
    }
  }

private:
  ros::NodeHandle n_;
  ros::Publisher pub_;
  ros::ServiceClient client_;
  ros::Timer timer_;
  bool first_time_;
} ;

}

using namespace laser_assembler ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "periodic_snapshotter");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ROS_INFO("Waiting for [build_cloud] to be advertised");
  ros::service::waitForService("build_cloud");
  ROS_INFO("Found build_cloud! Starting the snapshotter");
  PeriodicSnapshotter snapshotter;
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps! :-)

---

Originally posted by [redarean](https://answers.ros.org/users/4903/redarean/) with karma: 81 on 2014-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2015-04-26**:
Hi,

Can you help me with this question. I have the laser_assembler up and running with periodic_snapshotter. I want to convert the pointcloud to octomap using octomap server. However the pointcloud data required is pointcloud2. How do I convert the data to pointcloud2. Is there any default package.

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-10-12**:
Hi,
I follow the steps described but it doesn't work for me. I run a bag file, then launch the laser_scan_assembler.launch and finally the periodic snapshotter, but I got this:

INFO Published Cloud with 0 points

How could I solve it?
Thank you.

**Comment by [redarean](https://answers.ros.org/users/4903/redarean/) on 2015-10-12**:
Hi jcgarciaca,
Can you run "rosbag info" on your bagfile and update the question? It could be an issue of the pointcloud2 being expected instead of pointcloud.
Thanks!

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-10-12**:
Hi redarean, thanks for your answer. The rosbag info on my file is:

path:        2015-09-25-17-07-26.bag

version:     2.0

duration:    1:59s (119s)

start:       Sep 25 2015 17:07:27.47 (1443218847.47)

end:         Sep 25 2015 17:09:27.14 (1443218967.14)

size:        33.6 MB

messages:    71663

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-10-12**:
compression: none [44/44 chunks]

types:       rosgraph_msgs/Log     [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]

sensor_msgs/LaserScan [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2015-10-12**:
topics:      /rosout       7 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log     (3 connections)

/scan     71656 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Thank you